# The show and hide password incurred an attributeError

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I created a login form which I have a username and password field to login. The below of password field will have a chechbox to check whether the user to show or to hide their password before they click the login button. if they click to show password, the password field will show their actual password instead of '*' and the label will change to hide password. if they uncheck the checkbox, the password will indicate otherwise, this is how it works.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

class LoginWindow(MDScreen):
    pass

class MainWindow(MDScreen):
    pass

class password(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(LoginWindow(name='login')) 
        sm.add_widget(MainWindow(name='main'))
        return sm
    
    def show_password(self, checkbox, value):
        if value:
            self.root.ids.password_login.password = False
            self.root.ids.password_text.text = 'Hide password'
        else:
            self.root.ids.password_login.password = True
            self.root.ids.password_text.text = 'Show password'

Builder.load_string('''
<LoginWindow>:
    MDFloatLayout:
        size_hint: .79, .08
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .32}
        
        MDLabel:
            text: "Password"
            font_size: "14sp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 1.2}
        
        TextInput:
            id: password_login
            password: True
            text: ''
            size_hint_y: .75
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .49, "center_y": .6}
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            cursor_color: 0,0,0,1
            cursor_width: "2sp"
            font_size: "17sp"
            multiline: False
            
        MDFloatLayout:
            pos_hint:  {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .3} 
            size_hint_y:  .03
            md_bg_color: 120/255, 120/255, 120/255, 1

        MDCheckbox:
            size_hint: None, None          
            size: '48dp', '48dp'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.18,'center_y': 0.15}
            on_active: app.show_password(*args)
        
        MDLabel:
            id: password_text
            text: 'Show Password'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .73, 'center_y': .15}
''')
password().run()
```

The following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 961, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'password_login'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "d:\Learning App\kivyMD\test.py", line 68, in <module>
     password().run()
   File "D:\Learning App\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 955, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "D:\Learning App\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "D:\Learning App\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 339, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "D:\Learning App\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 383, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "D:\Learning App\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 334, in dispatch_input
     self.active = True
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 520, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 567, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 606, in kivy.properties.Property._dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1189, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "D:\Learning App\kivyMD\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 55, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "<string>", line 33, in <module>
   File "d:\Learning App\kivyMD\test.py", line 23, in show_password
     self.root.ids.password_login.password = False
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `show_password()` method you are incorrectly trying to access the `password_login` `TextInput`. The `root` of your `App` is the `ScreenManager` and it has no `ids`. You must traverse to the correct `Screen` before resorting to using `ids`. Try changing your `show_password()` like this:

```
def show_password(self, checkbox, value):
    if value:
        self.root.get_screen('login').ids.password_login.password = False
        self.root.get_screen('login').ids.password_text.text = 'Hide password'
    else:
        self.root.get_screen('login').ids.password_login.password = True
        self.root.get_screen('login').ids.password_text.text = 'Show password'
```